# Angular Datatable dtTrigger

Tags: angular, datatables, angular-datatables

Hi everyone I am trying to implement this angular datatables package into my application.

- https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/welcome

I have the table inside of a component called datatable. This is how I call this component in my parent.

`<datatable [cols]="cols" [data]="data"></datatable>`

This is my controller passing the data into my component.

```
getData(){
  this.dataService.getData().subscribe((data) => {
    this.data = data;
    this.isLoaded = true;
  });
}
```

The issue here is that I want to use dtTrigger to load only when my data has arrive like in the documentation here.

- https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/basic/angular-way

They have

```
[dtTrigger]="dtTrigger"
```

on the table and call next

```
this.dtTrigger.next();
```

when they get the data.

How do I achieve this with a datatable component rather than having it in my parent component.